# AWS lambda trigger not working when I upload a file using s3 presign url upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, pre-signed-url

I have made a lambda function that gets triggered on S3 file upload.

Whenever I upload a file manually the lambda trigger seems to be working. However, when I upload a file to the S3 bucket using S3 presign URLs (using API Gateway and another lambda function), the Lambda trigger does not get triggered even though the file gets uploaded successfully to S3 bucket.

I am sure if Lambda requires higher privileges to get triggered and process the file upon a presign URL upload or something.

Comment: Did the manually-uploaded object (that did trigger the lambda) have the exact same key as the object uploaded with the presigned-url (that failed to trigger the lambda)?

Comment: yes, it is the same file

Comment: What are the S3 notification `EventTypes` and `Filters`?  You said the keys ("folder/file.ext")  are the same, so any filters really should not matter.  Does your notification trigger exclude the `ObjectCreated POST` EventType?  Is your lambda notification handler perhaps ignoring the `ObjectCreated POST` EventType?

Comment: Basically, that's is what is happening. My lambda function is ignoring ObjectCreated POST when I successfully upload a media file to the s3 bucket. But somehow recognises it when I upload it to the s3 bucket through the console. But the event trigger is triggered by ObjectCreated

Comment: That is perfectly clear.  The reason for the previous comment was that it seems the root cause is likeliest found in the notification configuration / handler lambda logic, not in the upload itself.   FWIW, I have a similar setup - a presigned url upload trigger a lambda.

Comment: Can you share how you set it up as my presign URL upload (configured using API gateway & Lambda) is not triggering my second lambda function which should get triggered on S3 file upload

Comment: I am confused. Is this Lambda function triggered by an Amazon S3 event? If so, the code should be processing the `event['Records']` list (which can have multiple entries). Your code is looking like it is handling a response to an API Gateway event, rather than an S3 event?

Comment: I use the `go` sdk, so my specific code won't help.  I create `put` presigned urls.

Comment: I uploaded the second lambda function that gets triggered upon s3 upload  which is not getting triggered upon s3 presign URL upload. Please check it out above @John Rotenstein

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant, but this code only uses the _first_ record that is passed to the function (`file_obj= event['Records'][0]`). It is possible that multiple event records can be passed to an AWS Lambda function, and the function should loop through all records passed in. So, the question is whether the function is not being triggered _at all_ (which can be seen via CloudWatch Logs), or whether the function simply isn't processing every record passed to it. Are you saying that there is no record that the Lambda function is even _started_ when the upload is performed?

Comment: The function is not getting triggered, there isn't any record on Cloudwatch logs of when the file gets uploaded to the S3 bucket.

Comment: If CloudWatch Logs is not logging the execution of the AWS Lambda function, then something would appear to be wrong with the configuration of the Event on the S3 bucket. You might want to remove the configuration and try adding it again. If it still isn't working, then you should raise it with AWS Support (for which a Support subscription is required).

Comment: Your configured event should be `s3:ObjectCreated:*`, not `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`.

Comment: @jarmod My objectCreated is set to all

Comment: How are you uploading to the pre-signed URL? How confident are you that this is actually succeeding? You should also triple check the bucket and key you are supplying to the pre-signed calculation.

Comment: @jarmod   The file is getting uploaded successfully to the desired s3 bucket. However, the lambda function that should be triggered afterwards (upon s3 upload) is not getting triggered. I am not sure if S3 presign URLs uploads in particular do not trigger lambda function or something

Comment: It shouldn't matter, but how are you actually uploading to the pre-signed URL? Command line PUT or POST with curl, Node,js app via request, browser via Axios, something else?

Comment: What does that mean? What is "a static file connected to an API gateway"? The reason I keep probing here is that the most obvious reason that this is not working is that you are mistaken, and we just need to work out how.

Comment: @jarmod I am uploading the file through a static website. To handle the upload I am using API gateway and another lambda function. Which is working fine on the upload side

Comment: @jarmod What I am trying to understand is the fact that the lambda gets triggered when I upload a file  using S3 put object, but when I use presign URL. The lambda does not get triggered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239009/discussion-between-jarmod-and-bemtg).

Comment: @BemTG I tried using serverless framework. and able to trigger a lambda whenever a file is uploaded to s3. [check this](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/s3/#using-existing-buckets).

but I got into an validating file error while uploading file through presignedURL [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71004360/14580983)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to a very similar problem by changing filename characters used to generate the s3 presigned URL:

My goal was uploading files to s3 using the AWS API, and invoking a lambda function once that was completed.

The lambda function was working when I used the console to add a file to an s3 bucket.

When I used the API to add a file to an s3 bucket, the lambda function would trigger properly, but then generate an error : 'An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden'

I was using the python lambda code on this official [AWS resource page](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/lambda-copy-s3-files).

I found that any 'space' characters in the filename were being url encoded into '%20' in the API call and these were in turn being being substituted with a '+' character by the python lambda code. The '+' character in the filename was causing the lambda function to generate a 403 forbidden response.

Removing space characters in the filename solved the problem for me.